# When using Kotlin Exposed, how do I handle missing values for numbers in an sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have an sqlite data base that entries similar this example:

```
0|some_text0|123.456||some_other_text0
1|some_text1||456.789|some_other_text1
```

So as you can see the 3rd and 4th column are numbers, but in some records the data in the column is empty.

I defined the interface using something similar to this example.

```
object Foos : IntIdTable("foos") {
    val sequelId = integer("id").primaryKey()
    val text0 = text("text0")
    val num0 = float("num0").nullable()
    val num1 = float("num1").nullable()
    val text1 = text("text1")
}

class Foo(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Foo>(Foos)

    var sequelId by Foos.sequelId
    var text0 by Foos.text0
    var num0 by Foos.num0
    var num1 by Foos.num1
    var text1 by Foos.text
}
```

If I query a record that contains a missing value and try to access the field I throw an exception such as java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.math.Float?

for example:

```
val x = queryResult0.num1 //fails
```

I can get passed this via:

```
val x = try { queryResult0.num1 } catch(e: Exception) { null } // works I get a value or null
```

My current "hacky" solution is to add a second set of getters for the fields such this:

```
 class Foo(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Foo>(Foos)

    var sequelId by PinTimings.sequelId
    var text0 by Foos.text0
    var num0 by Foos.num0
    var num1 by Foos.num1
    var text1 by Foos.text
    val num0x : Float?
       get() = try { num0 } catch(e: Exception) { null } 
    val num1x : Float?
       get() = try { num1 } catch(e: Exception) { null }
 }
```

Then `queryResut0.num1x` provides what I need.

What's the right way to handle this kind of situation?

FYI: I am using the following setup

- Kotlin: 1.2.61
- Exposed: org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.17.7
- JDBC: org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.32.3.2

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me without any hacks. `Foo.all().forEach { println("${it.num0} ${it.num1}") }` prints `123.456 null` and `null 456.789` as expected. What is your query? What JDBC driver do you use?

Comment: Thanks for trying this.  What I posted was an simplified example of my real data.  I should try and set up this exact contrived case and see it works this.  I am currently using the hack I described.  only instead of naming the new getter as something like num0x, I did something like this `var _num0 by Foos.num0`, and then the getter is `val num0` , referencing the `_num0`

Comment: I was using Kotlin 1.4.10 (don't think it matters actually), Exposed 0.24.1 and the same JDBC driver. Will update of Exposed fix this for you?

Comment: Are you sure that the column type of num0 and num2 is Float and not Varchar in the database?